# Running cURL on Windows using Xojo

Tags: windows, curl

I am sending a short SSL command to Twilio using Xojo.

On the Mac, cURL is built-in and so it is simple to execute a shell command.

Since cURL is not installed on Windows, is there one version of cURL that will run on all Windows versions (or does my app installer, Inno, need to determine with Windows OS is running and install that specific version)?

Any advice as to what files need to be included would be greatly appreciated.

Once installed, how would the cURL command on the Windows machine differ from the Mac?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some time searching, I did finally come up with a solution.

1. Install cURL - downloaded from [here](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/) with SSL.

If you download the installer file (with the .msi extension), it creates a C:\Program Files\curl directory and extracts the files to that directory. You can place the files in whatever directory you choose, just so long as you reference it properly.

2. In Xojo, you create a shell command similar to the code here:

   Dim sh As New Shell

   Dim command As String

   command = """C:\Program Files\curl\bin\curl"" -X POST https://myurl.com"

   sh.Execute(command)

Note that C:\Program Files\curl\bin\curl is within double-quotes. This is because there is a space within "Program Files".  If you do not place the address within double-quotes, everything after the space is considered a parameter and will generate an error.

IMPORTANT NOTE: Windows does not recognize the single-quote, so all single-quotes need to be replaced with double-quotes.

In addition, on the Mac OS, the "-" character needs to be escaped with a backslash "-". These backslashes need to be removed when translating the cURL command from Mac to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need cURL to send a POST. Take a look to the POST method of the HTTPsocket object.

From the official Xojo documentation:

This example does a synchronous POST to a service that returns what you POSTed to it as JSON:

```
Dim d As New Dictionary

d.Value("Test") = "TestValue"
d.Value("Value2") = "Testing"

Socket.SetFormData(d)

// This service simply returns the post data as the result
Dim result As String
result = Socket.Post("http://httpbin.org/post", 30) // Synchronous

result = DefineEncoding(result, Encodings.UTF8)

MsgBox(result)
```

To do this asynchronous, call Post without a timeout:

```
Dim d As New Dictionary

d.Value("Test") = "TestValue"
d.Value("Value2") = "Testing"

Socket.SetFormData(d)

// This service simply returns the post data as the result
Socket.Post("http://httpbin.org/post")
```

The results will be available in the PageReceived event handler in the content parameter.

```
Sub PageReceived(url As String, httpStatus As Integer, headers As InternetHeaders, content As String)
  Dim data As String
  data = DefineEncoding(content, Encodings.UTF8)

  ResultArea.Text = data
End Sub
```